# "The AudioContext was not allowed to start." warning when using useSound hook in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, howler.js

So I'm using useSound hook. But It does not work in following simple example:

```js
import useSound from 'use-sound';

import boopSfx from '../../sounds/boop.mp3';

const BoopButton = () => {
  const [play] = useSound(boopSfx);

  return <button onClick={play}>Boop!</button>;
};
```

I get following warning in console:

```
howler.js:2500 The AudioContext was not allowed to start. It must be resumed (or created) after a user gesture on the page
```